# Google Geochart - Unable to set region to a specific province

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-visualization

I'm trying to display City markers for cities within the Province of Quebec Map.
Based on google documentation, we should be able to set the `resolution` option to `provinces` and set the `region` to the ISO code (Eg: US-GA..). When i try with `CA-QC` (Found this code [here on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-2:CA).

When I try this, the map `<div>` displays this message : **Requested map doest not exist**

See Fiddle:

```js
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

      function drawRegionsMap() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['City', 'Popularity'],
          ['Quebec', 200],
          ['Montreal', 300],
          ['Sorel-Tracy', 400],
          ['Boucherville', 500]
        ]);

        var options = {  enableRegionInteractivity: 'true',resolution: 'provinces', region:'CA-QC'};

        var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('regions_div'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1.1','packages':['geochart']}]}"></script>
       <div id="regions_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

I there a way/workaround to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not seem possible to set regions in this country.

According to [Visualization: Geochart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart):

> 'provinces' - Supported only for country regions and US state regions.
>   Not supported for all countries; please test a country to see whether
>   this option is supported.

But you could consider another option, draw popularity using [circle markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/circle-simple) instead of `geocharts` as demonstrated below:

```js
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 6,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(46.579246, -72.024826)
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    displayPopularity(map);
}


function displayPopularity(map) {
    var citymap = {};
    citymap['Quebec'] = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(46.769492, -71.290357),
        population: 200
    };
    citymap['Montreal'] = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(45.510845, -73.567888),
        population: 300
    };
    citymap['Sorel-Tracy'] = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(46.421575, -73.118540),
        population: 400
    };
    citymap['Boucherville'] = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(45.601591, -73.438919),
        population: 500
    };


    for (var city in citymap) {
        var populationOptions = {
            strokeColor: '#00FF00',
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            fillColor: '#00FF00',
            fillOpacity: 0.35,
            map: map,
            center: citymap[city].center,
            radius: Math.sqrt(citymap[city].population) * 1000
        };
        var cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle(populationOptions);


        (function (cityCircle,city) {

            //create info window
            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: city
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(cityCircle, 'click', function(ev) {
                infoWindow.setPosition(cityCircle.getCenter());
                infoWindow.open(map);
            });
        })(cityCircle,city);
    }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Popularity map</title>
    <style>
        html, body, #map-canvas {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, That a way of doing it, with that technique, would it be possible to make the circles interactive? (clickable or show info-bubble)?

Comment: Sure,  info window could be displayed once the circle marker is clicked.  You could try the updated example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vgrem/fm5rz2vf/1/)

Comment: Maybe your code hasn't been saved, there is no click events on the circle

Comment: Your solution is a good workaround, thanks. I'm still searching for a javascript/SVG map library that will show just borders and that I can zoom to a predefined level and also put markers/info window. Until then, I'll use your solution.

Answer (score -1):

change the region to `region:'CA'`

Comment: Using region:'CA' displays the Map of Canada, I want the map of a single province.